# Does the code generated by Adobe Edge conform to good programming practice?

Tags: css, html, adobe

I'm a long-time as3 designer who wants to dip a toe into the html5 pool. Adobe edge seems happy, but does it make code that anyone wants to look at?

Answer (score 0):

No, not at all.

The basic page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adobe EDGE TEST August 1, 2011</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="edge_includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="edge_includes/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="edge_includes/edge.0.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="edge_includes/edge.symbol.0.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="adobe_edge_test_edge.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="adobe_edge_test_edge.css"/>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->


<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>

</head><body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(4000);">
    <div id="stage" class="symbol_stage">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which looks nice, till you notice that there is no content, so SEO is completely ruined.

It uses JS to create and animate the content, and doesn't use CSS transitions or animation. Here's a snippet of the Javascript:

```
      dom: [
        {
            id:'Text1',
            type:'text',
            rect:[98,120,385,150],
            text:"A test using Edge",
            font:["Arial Black, Gadget, sans-serif",[24,""],"rgba(0,0,0,1)","normal","none",""],
        },
        {
            id:'RoundRect2',
            type:'rect',
            rect:[187,332,45,41],
            borderRadius:[47,47,47,47],
            fill:['rgba(255,255,0,1)'],
            stroke:[0,"rgb(0, 0, 0)","none"],
        },
        {
            id:'Text3',
            type:'text',
            rect:[79,270,0,0],
            text:"Here's another paragraph",
            align:"auto",
            font:["Times",16,"rgba(0,0,0,1)","normal","none","normal"],
        },
```

Here's some of the animation bit:

```
{ id: "eid29", tween: [ "transform", "#Rectangle1", "skewY", '43deg', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '0deg'}], position: 220, duration: 280, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid2", tween: [ "color", "#stage", "background-color", 'rgba(215,215,215,1.00)', { animationColorSpace: 'RGB', valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: 'rgba(215,215,215,1.00)'}], position: 0, duration: 0, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid308", tween: [ "color", "#stage", "background-color", 'transparent', { animationColorSpace: 'RGB', valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: 'rgba(215,215,215,1)'}], position: 750, duration: 750, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid76", tween: [ "transform", "#Text3", "translateY", '-267px', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '0px'}], position: 750, duration: 250, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid15", tween: [ "style", "#Rectangle1", "opacity", '0.84705882352941', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '0.84705882352941'}], position: 65, duration: 0, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid17", tween: [ "style", "#Rectangle1", "opacity", '0.84705882352941', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '0.84705882352941'}], position: 500, duration: 0, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid72", tween: [ "transform", "#RoundRect2", "scaleY", '3.07', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '3.07'}], position: 735, duration: 0, easing: "easeInCirc" },
            { id: "eid98", tween: [ "transform", "#RoundRect2", "scaleY", '3.07', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '3.07'}], position: 940, duration: 0, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid67", tween: [ "transform", "#RoundRect2", "rotateZ", '-85deg', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '-85deg'}], position: 735, duration: 0, easing: "easeInCirc" },
            { id: "eid100", tween: [ "transform", "#RoundRect2", "rotateZ", '-85deg', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '-85deg'}], position: 940, duration: 0, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid93", tween: [ "transform", "#Text4", "translateY", '-14px', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '0px'}], position: 750, duration: 250, easing: "linear" },
            { id: "eid71", tween: [ "transform", "#RoundRect2", "scaleX", '3.07', { valueTemplate: undefined, fromValue: '3.07'}], position: 735, duration: 0, easing: "easeInCirc" },
```

So, no content, no transitions/animation and the JS is an unmaintainable mess.

Other than that, it's fine.

Comment: Very sad, the interface actually seems smart (unlike flash)and the timeline looked useful for once. Have you seen their thing to convert between as3 and html5 canvas? (forget the name atm)

Comment: re js, yes its ugly but it seems man-readable, you got an animation with a uid (eid, whatever), just use the uid to call it, no?

Comment: Sure, but if you then need to add a new element with a new animation, I suspect that it will get complex fast.

Comment: True, but IMHO not so relevant. They expect you to exhaust necessary animations at design time, which is a very reasonable expectation. If you are a designer, why would you code animation? OTOH the format seems standard, why would you not just copy, paste, and change eid?

Comment: The real problem is that I don't see how to use custom tween libraries, eg greensock in as3. Native as3 tweens are kinda sad, i dunno if thats the case for js.

Comment: The main issue is the lack of actual content in the HTML – this means search engines won't find the page without some serious messing around with this code. The rest of it is just annoyance, but the lack of content is a killer.